# How to apply two conditions in the same If statement?

Tags: vba, if-statement

```vb
Public Sub master()
    Dim checker As Date

    checker = Time
    If (checker > TimeValue("09:15:00")) & (checker <= TimeValue("12:00:00")) Then
        MsgBox "On time"
    Else
        MsgBox "Not the right time"
    End If

End Sub
```

It is giving an error on the if statement

> "Type Mismatch" Run Time error 13

I have also tried Now, `checker = Now`

Comment: Although, should be closed as typo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VBA the & operator is for string concatenation. You need to use "and":

```
 If (checker > TimeValue("09:15:00")) and (checker <= TimeValue("12:00:00")) Then
```